# angularjs ng-paste not updating model value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I have used `ng-paste` for textarea while pasting the link in textarea, i am calling a custom function to store that value. Please refer following code

```
<textarea rows="1" ng-model="myObj.content"
              ng-paste="getContent(myObj)">
 </textarea>

$scope.getContent = function(a){
    console.log(a.content);
}
```

But in console always I am getting `undefined` value. How can I get my object value?

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

Passing model to function does not really make sense since you have already specified `ng-model`, so it's value will be updated as user types something into the `textbox`. If you want to track changes you can setup a `$watch` for your model or specify a function using `ng-change`.

If you want to know what user pasted, then that's another story. Handling `ng-paste` can be tricky. To access the actual event, easiest is to include `jQuery` before `angularjs` and then do e.g. following:

**HTML template**

```
<textarea rows="3"
          placeholder="copy/paste here..."
          ng-init="content = null"
          ng-model="content" 
          ng-paste="paste($event.originalEvent)">
</textarea>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.paste = function (event) {
  var item = event.clipboardData.items[0];
  item.getAsString(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/ea5y5j

---

[image]

Comment: what is $event.originalEvent responsability?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$timeout` to call your paste callback after the model has been updated.

```
$scope.getContent = function(a){
   $timeout(function () {console.log(a.content)});
}
```